# numpy.sort() error ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

When I use *numpy* to sort an array
this problem come up :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Desktop/LIP/complier/num/f_t.py", line 75, in <module>
frogs[i].sort(order='length')
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

But if I comment these codes,it is ok

```
        # if len < temp_len:
        #     r_w[i]['length'] = len
        # else:
        #     r_w[i]['points'] = r_g['points']
        #     r_w[i]['length'] = r_g['length']
```

Why?

`r_g` is the best route,`r_w` are the worst routes in every group,`r_b` is the best route in every group.
I want to change the worst route for 5 times in a loop.

Here is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
# __author__ = 'youzipi'
import numpy as np

def cal_length(route):
    length = 0
    for i in range(POINTS_NUM):
        p1 = points[route[i]]
        p2 = points[route[(i + 1) % POINTS_NUM]]
        length += np.linalg.norm(p1 - p2)
    return length

POINTS_NUM = 10
ROUTES_NUM = 50
routetype = np.dtype({
    'names': ['points', 'length'],
    'formats': ['O', 'f']})
routes = np.zeros([(ROUTES_NUM)], dtype=routetype)
points = np.random.rand(POINTS_NUM, 2) * 10
print "points=", points

for index in range(ROUTES_NUM):
    temp = np.random.permutation(range(POINTS_NUM))
    length = cal_length(temp)
    routes[index] = (temp, length)


print "after sort"
routes.sort(order=('length'))
print routes
frogs = np.zeros([5, 10], dtype=routetype)

for i in range(5):
    t = 0
    for j in range(ROUTES_NUM):
        if j%5 == i:
            frogs[i][j/5]['points'] = routes[j]['points']
            frogs[i][j/5]['length'] = routes[j]['length']

for i in range(5):
    print "frogs", i
    print frogs[i]
p = routes['length']
print p
r_g = routes[0]
print "r_g", r_g
r_b = frogs[:, 0]
print "r_b", r_b
r_w = frogs[:, 9]
print "r_w", r_w


#def update_frogs():
#global r_w, r_b, r_b
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        cut = int(np.random.rand(1)[0] * 10)
        ran = np.random.permutation(range(POINTS_NUM))
        print 'r_w', r_w[i]
        print 'r_b', r_b[i]
        temp_len = r_w[i]['length']
        r_w[i]['points'] = np.hstack((r_b[i]['points'][:cut], np.linspace(-1, -1, 10)[cut:]))
        for t in ran:
            if t not in r_w[i]['points']:
                r_w[i]['points'][cut] = t
                cut = cut + 1
            if cut >= POINTS_NUM:
                break
        len = cal_length(r_w[i]['points'])
        # if len < temp_len:
        #     r_w[i]['length'] = len
        # else:
        #     r_w[i]['points'] = r_g['points']
        #     r_w[i]['length'] = r_g['length']
        frogs[i].sort(order='length')#trackbreak here!!
        r_w[i]['points'] = frogs[i, 9]['points']
        r_w[i]['length'] = frogs[i, 9]['length']
        print "after"
        print 'f_w', r_w[i]
        print 'f_b', r_b[i]
```

Comment: you shouldn't use `len` as a name for one of your variables.  it's a built-in function.

Comment: frogs is a set of groups for example：routes = [1,2,3,4,5,6],frogs=[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]

Comment: frogs is an numpy.array

Comment: ah, sorry, i missed that you included the code where you define `frogs`.

Comment: There are lots of SO questions about this error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the 'related' column - there are lots of questions about this ValueError.

The most likely cause is that you generate a list or array of True/False values and then try to use it in a Python `if/else` context.

So instead of holding your hand and analyzing all of your code, I'm going to suggest that you look at the variables in the those problem lines, and determine which are generating multiple values.  Actually, since there is only on `if` statement, it has to be `len < temp_len`.  Other or other of those 2 variables is a array, not a scalar.

```
    # if len < temp_len:
    #     r_w[i]['length'] = len
    # else:
    #     r_w[i]['points'] = r_g['points']
    #     r_w[i]['length'] = r_g['length']
```