# Conditional Plotting with Numpy and Pyplot

Tags: python, numpy, plot, comparison, conditional-statements

I am trying to plot a function that is defined conditionally. Specifically:
U(x) = (2**delta)/((D-d)**delta)*(D/2 - (x-x0))**delta , for abs(x-x0) less than D/2 and 0 otherwise.

But my problem is that I want to have x, x0 as numpy arrays, because this is how I use them in the rest of my actual code.

I have set-up the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
AD = 0.2
D = 0.4
delta = 8

def Parabolic(x, delta, D, AD):
    x0 = np.round(x)
    tempx = np.abs(x-x0)
    tempD = D/2*np.ones(len(x))
    if tempx<tempD:
        return ((2**delta)/(D-AD)**delta)*(D/2 - (x-x0))**delta
    else:
        return 0

figure = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8), dpi=72)  
xmin = -1.0
xmax = 1.0
X = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,1000)
plt.plot(X, Parabolic(X, delta=8, D=0.4, AD=0.2))
```

Obviously this example does not work, since the line `tempx<tempD` raises the error that a Truth-value of a list is ambiguous.

I searched around the documentation of numpy and found the function np.less(tempx, tempD). But if I replace `tempx < tempD` with `np.less(tempx, tempD)` it still doesn't work since once again I am asking for a truth value of an entire list. I understand that the problem is not with numpy, but with my inability to understand how to use the logical functions that numpy provides.

I am sorry if this answered some way in another post, I searched in this forum but could not find something else besides the `curve()` method. However I want to keep my numpy.array format for use in my actual codes. I would bet that the answer must be very simple, I just can't think of it.

Comment: On your error, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30081652/901925 and its sidebar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this which uses numpy logical arrays:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
AD = 0.2
D = 0.4
delta = 8

def Parabolic(x, delta, D, AD):
    rtn_arr = np.zeros(len(x))
    x0 = np.round(x)
    tempx = np.abs(x-x0)
    tempD = D/2*np.ones(len(x))
    lgc_arr = tempx<tempD
    x_cut = x[lgc_arr]
    x0_cut = x0[lgc_arr]
    rtn_arr[lgc_arr] = ((2**delta)/(D-AD)**delta)*(D/2 - (x_cut-x0_cut))**delta
    return rtn_arr

figure = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8), dpi=72)
xmin = -1.0
xmax = 1.0
X = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,1000)
plt.plot(X, Parabolic(X, delta=8, D=0.4, AD=0.2))
```

Comment: Well, this is exactly what I was looking for.
I managed to solve my problem using python lists and append, but of course it wasn't that good. Yours was what I was looking. I did not know that one could use `x_cut = x[lgc_array]` in order to get only the elements that correspond to true! One last thing: Could you explain me how the line `lgc_arr = tempx<tempD` worked? Does numpy arrays automatically change how  the relation/comparison operators work and returns automatically a numpy array?

Comment: `tempx<tempD` is returning a array in your code as well.  But you try to use that result in a Python `if` context.  Using any numby boolean array in a context that expects a scalar boolean produces the `ValueError`.

Comment: @GeorgeDatseris Exactly as you say. The numpy arrays redefine the conditional operators (which can be done for any custom class https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) so that using `>, <` etc. on numpy arrays returns numpy arrays. Then `tempx<tempD` is an array of boolean values, which can be used to do array slicing with `x[lgc_array]`.

Answer (score 3):

Parabolic must be a ufunc, so you can't  put python test in your code.

a simple workaround is  :

```
def Parabolic(x, delta, D, AD):
    x0 = np.round(x)
    tempx = np.abs(x-x0)
    tempD = D/2*np.ones(len(x))
    u=(((2**delta)/(D-AD)**delta)*(D/2 - (x-x0))**delta)
    u[tempx>=tempD]=0
    return u
```

or  to avoid unnecessary computations:

```
def Parabolic2(x, delta, D, AD):
    x0 = np.round(x)
    tempx = np.abs(x-x0)
    tempD = D/2*np.ones(len(x))
    u= zeros_like(x)
    valid=tempx<tempD
    u[valid]=(((2**delta)/(D-AD)**delta)*(D/2 - (x-x0)[valid])**delta)
    return u
```

The second is slighty faster :

```
In [141]: %timeit Parabolic(x,8,.4,.2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 310 µs per loop

In [142]: %timeit Parabolic2(x,8,.4,.2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 218 µs per loop
```

Comment: This is also a nice workaround, and quite simple code-wise. However it does mean that I have to calculate the function for all values, small and big ones. And this will take a lot of time in the normal code. I intend to use the first answer for both very high and very small values of the `u` function, mainly to avoid computations.

Comment: I don't think the second version will work as the length of `u[tempx<tempD]` will be less than the array returned on the right side of this equation.

Comment: I tried to run the code and it is true that it doesn't complete for the reason you said.